# Why won't this code work to create my bar plot? It's not changing any of the axis titles/size etc as instructed to

Tags: r, bar-chart

```
png("barplot.png", width=1600, height=600) 
barplot(biodiv, xlab="Taxa", ylab="Number of species", ylim=c(0,600), cex.names= 1.5, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5)
dev.off()
```

My graph looks like this from previous code but wont change when i type in the new code above

[image]

Comment: You are saving the barplot in a .png file so it won't appear on your RStudio session, it is only saved in your current directory

Comment: follow up to @Basti 's comment.  ```dev.off()``` also closes your active device (plot window).